# Good protocol for multiple conditional spatial and attribute based selections using ArcPy while avoiding saving to disc

Tags: arcpy, python

I am running multiple conditional selections, both where clauses with attributes and location based selections.  I want to build functions, possibly within classes that are reusable and can pipe to each other or be scripted in different orders based on workflow.  I DON'T want to `CopyFeatures_management` constantly for intermediate features classes written to disc.  I'm hoping for Python type:

```
temp = load_data(fp_data)
temp2 = function1(temp)
temp3 = function2(temp2)
CopyFeatures_management(temp3)
```

Simple example of current workflow:

```
def select_by_location(fp_select, fp_location, distance_string, fp_out):

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fp_select, 'in_lyr')
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fp_location, 'location_lyr')
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('in_lyr', 'within_a_distance', 'location_lyr', '5 Miles')
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('in_lyr', fp_out)
```

Call function with first feature layer:

`select_by_location(fp1, fp2, '5 Miles')`

Now take output and select with another feature layer:

`fp_location2 = 'path/to/another/file'`

`arcpy.select_by_location(fp_out, fp_location2, '3 Miles', fp_out2)`

What is a good protocol to avoid saving to disc constantly when in ArcPy world?

Comment: You mean, instead of using the `in_memory` workspace?

Comment: That'll work.  Thanks Vince!  Took me a bit to respond because I have been grappling with the difference between ```in_memory``` workspace and simply using ```MakeFeatureLayer_management```.  I found a good post from Stack Exchange with good links and comments as well.  Still slightly confused as to difference between ```MakeFeatureLayer_management``` and ```CopyFeatures_management``` with ```in_memory``` specified but alas...for another Q.  Here is the link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72193/difference-between-make-feature-layer-data-management-and-using-in-memory-work)