# Error 00358 when using arcpy.SelectLayerByAttributeManagement

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, in-memory, error-000358

All I'm trying to do is use SelectLayerByAttribute to select all lines less than 5.1 meters. However, no matter what query I try I keep getting
"error 000358 invalid expression" when I run the script as a tool. I have already tried using various combinations of escape characters and string concatenations like ' \"Shape_Length\" < \'5.1\' ' and '\"Shape_Length\" <' + '5.1'. I've also have tried putting Shape_Length in {}'s.  I tried doing the same query in the python window in ArcMap and all I have to do is "Shape_Length < 5.1" and it works just fine. I've never been so stumped. Anyone have anymore ideas on what to try?

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import da

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.SetLogHistory(False)
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

og_polyline = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
polyline =arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(og_polyline,r"in_memory/lines")

layer=arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(polyline,"thelayer.lyr")

calc_fields=["SHAPE@","OBJECTID"]

norepeatlist=[]

query="Shape_Length < 5.1"

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

Comment: query="Shape_Length < + 5.1" should be query="Shape_Length < 5.1". When querying the field delimiters aren't strictly needed and because the shape_length field is a double the value should not be quoted.

Comment: My apologies that + sign was a typo I accidentally left in the code. I already tried "Shape_Length < 5.1" and the error is still happening.

Comment: Does that field exist? You're copying to an in_memory workspace but from what? If it's a shapefile then the field doesn't necessarily exist. Note that polyline should be r"in_memory/lines", at the moment it's a gpResult object.

Comment: Shape_Length does not exist in memory. I'll try to find a duplicate that says more.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/53904/115

Comment: You should be able to add a field called length then use Calculate Field !shape.length! to populate.. unless you need the shape length in a different coordinate system then it's a bit more complicated.